# Android java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to print the value that has been clicked on in the listView, but then i'm getting the following exception:

```
07-04 10:40:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 10:40:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): java.lang.ClassCastException:      android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
07-04 10:40:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at com.passwordkeeper.ui.ActivityHomeScreen$1.onItemClick(ActivityHomeScreen.java:88)
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelList);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    createList();
    displayList();
}
```

The createList function is working properly. Here is my displayList method:

```
public void displayList(){
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_home_screen, R.id.listTextView, mAccountNames));
    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            Log.v("mSelectedProduct", product);
        }           
    });
}
```

My xml code for the file activity_home_screen.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Any help would be useful!

Thank you.

Comment: post your xml code here..

Comment: mTextView should be TextView Type

Comment: view which returns text as string product, in onItemClick method is giving you classcast excpetion, check for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            TextView txtview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);
            String product = txtview.getText().toString();
            Log.v("mSelectedProduct", product);
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
String product = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The View you are getting inside OnItemClickListener will return the parent layout ,That is LinearLayout in your case.

you can get your textview by doing following :

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            TextView txtview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listTextView);
            String product = txtview.getText().toString();
            Log.v("mSelectedProduct", product);
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            TextView textview= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TEXTVIEW_ID);
            String product = textView.getText().toString();
            Log.v("mSelectedProduct", product);
        }           
    });
```

Replace "TEXTVIEW_ID" with the id of textview you have given in list view item xml(If not given, give one).